# Adding AWS permissions to users

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to add permissions to a user at AWS:

1. I was able to add the permission for S3 - user sees all buckets just like the root account.
2. When I try to add the permission for SES - user does not see the validated domains which the
   root account sees.
3. When I try to add the permission for the ElasticsearchService, the service doesn't even come up when I follow the "Add permissions" procedure, but the service does come up when I click "Add inline policy". When I add the inline policy for the ElasticsearchService, the user does not see the domain which the root account sees.

Is my understanding of this wrong? Why aren't the SES/ElasticsearchService permissions working just like S3 permissions? When I add a permission policy, I would expect the user to see the same in those services as the root.

Comment: Do you have the full IAM policy? Additionally are there any denys?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The root account has full IAM policy. I tried also adding AdministratorAccess permission to the user account, which, as I understand, should give the user full access to everything. When I do that, the user also seems to have full IAM access. But the user still can't see the SES validated domains and ElasticsearchService domain.

Comment: Is the account a part of an organisation, or AWS educate? And are there any other policies attached?

Comment: No. The organisation is not created yet, also not educate. At the moment, the user account has only one additional policy, the IAMUserChangePassword, which should not be a problem. Also, whatever I try for S3 - works (direct permission, copy from another user, administrator access); for the other two services - none of that works.

Comment: Hmm if you grant the AdministratorAccess and that is the only other policy then the permissions should be there for those services. Is it only for this use or all users?

Comment: This is the only user account at the moment (mine). There was another belonging to a person who is no longer working on the project.